# php add facebook sdk to the composer

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I am reading this official facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0 page.

I want to add the facebook sdk to my project

I tried to do this:
`composer require facebook/php-sdk` in the root of my project and I got this

```
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommend
ed to update it by running "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-
update" to get the latest version.
Please provide a version constraint for the facebook/php-sdk requirement: **4**
```

as you see, I have chosen 4, then I got this error message:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package facebook/php-sdk could not be found in any version,
there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> f
or more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common
 problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

why is that please? notice please that I didn't add anything to my `composer.json`.

I opened the `composer.json` and I found this line:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
    },
```

so should I change it to :

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
          "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*" 
    },
```

or should I keep it and add a new `require` entity like this:

```
"require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
  }
```

Comment: To answer your question about syntax, you should add new requirements to the single require hash, don't create new ones.

Comment: @Cameron okay let me try that and I will update you

Comment: @Cameron should I add that line to the `require`? or should I do this `composer require facebook/php-sdk-v4` or both?

Comment: sorry, just add it to your existing `require` hash. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just try and add `facebook/php-sdk-4` to your existing `require` hash and then run `composer update`.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*" 
}
```

Comment: I did that and now a lot of things are being downloaded, I hope this won't crashed my already working project

Comment: I got this `facebook/php-sdk-v4 suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Allows for implementa
tion of the Guzzle HTTP client)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader` and a lot of things have been downloaded, how to know please if the facebook skd has been installed or not?

Comment: It shouldn't crash your project. To remove the package from your project then just remove the entry `"facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"` from `require` and run `composer update facebook/php-sdk-v4`

Comment: I don't want to remove it, I want to know if it is installed now or not. isn't there any folder that I should see that contains it?

Comment: You should see the downloaded files under your `vendor` folder. Composer should automatically preload the SDK so you should be able to start using it in your project immediately.

Comment: Cool! Good luck with the rest of your project :D